# Mismatch in SCSI controllers between vSphere and Linux using pvscsi driver

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, redhat, paravirtualization

Using RHEL6 and vSphere 5.5.

System was previously using LSI Parallel scsi controller.  After switching to Paravirtual SCSI controller, the SCSI controllers (and therefor disk IDs) are not matching in the OS.

For example: VM has 4 SCSI Controllers.  1st controller has the OS (Scsi ID 0:0) and another disk (0:1).  The controller shows up in vSphere as "SCSI Controller 0".  After switching all 4 controllers to Paravirtual, Vmware's "SCSI Controller 0" shows up as the 2nd controller in the OS, and SCSI Controller 3 show up as the 1st controller.  This causes an issue if we're trying to match up the disks to expand or remove them from vmware.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We haven't run into this specific problem but we've had something similar. NICs turned up inside the operating systems in a different order than in vSphere. We assumed that it had to do with the virtual PCI slots the vNICs were in. Maybe the virtual PCI slots the SCSI controllers are connected to changed when you switched from LSI Parallel to pvSCSI?

Can you change the controllers of another VM and check if the PCI slots change, too?

I've written about our vNIC problem [here](https://serverfault.com/a/611040/221034), maybe this helps.